# Sonarqube 4.5.1 not displaying metrics even though analysis is successful in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube-scan

I configured a Sonar ANT job in jenkins with sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName and sonar.projectVersion during February month. After build success, the sonar dashboard of ant job displayed the issues/metrics in sonarqube widgets.

But now (April month), the dashboard of ant job is not displaying the issues/metrics in SonarQube widgets.
when i saw in Time machine of that project, the previously analysis for the project was present.

I am not sure which event is causing this issue.

Could anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Note: Sonarqube version: 4.5.1 and  SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.4

Comment: Any suggestion or theory is welcomed. Thanks

Comment: What changed in your configuration?
Could you share the log of your analysis?

Comment: Any suggestion? I'm facing the same problem.